Rewrite url apache container docker-compose
I have a container running apache. This Apache loads an http with a folder called "oca", inside it there is a bundles.json where there is an object with the ids of some products and each id has an object with the path to access the product.
Bundles.json example:
{
  "UdaLdkzFHVVjydyarmP8h5-default": { "path": "UdaLdkzFHVVjydyarmP8h5-default/bundle.json" }
}

Currently, the default would be for me to create a file UdaLdkzFHVVjydyarmP8h5-default.json. As it stands today, I would have to create a folder: UdaLdkzFHVVjydyarmP8h5-default and inside it a bundle.json file and in the bundles.json file add its id and path. Is there any way I can just throw UdaLdkzFHVVjydyarmP8h5-default.json into Docker and ask it to show this file when accessing: oca/UdaLdkzFHVVjydyarmP8h5-default/bundle.json?
My docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.5'

services:
  apache:
    image: httpd:latest
    container_name: apache-oca
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
      - ./oca:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/oca

Importants lines httpd.conf:
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/oca">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^oca/([^/]+)/bundle\.json$ /oca/$1.json [L]
</Directory>

I added the line "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" in the httpd of the apache container and added this line: "RewriteRule ^oca/([^/]+)/bundle.json$ /oca/$1.json [L]" But even restarting the container doesn't change anything, it doesn't give an error in the container, it continues as if I hadn't changed anything.

Hi, this is exactly how docker works :-). Search for docker volumes, and how to persist data from restart to restart
